# Freeform Pro - Email Recipient from Channel

Tags: multi-site-manager, solspace-freeform

I'm trying to have a [Freeform Pro](http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/freeform/) on my site that not only emails the site owner when it's submitted but an external email contact as well.

The external email is a field from a channel called company. I was hoping something like this could work:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="companies" limit="1" site="default_site"}    
{exp:freeform:form form_name="el_list_form" required="name|email|phone|company" return="/search" recipient1="{company_email}"}
...
{/exp:freeform:form}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

At the moment it emails the `admin_notify` in the freeform settings just fine but will not email the `company_email` contact. I tried just sticking in my own email manually and it doesn't seem to like that either.

I tried to see if it was my mail in general that was the issue by sending out a site communication message but that sent just fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a parsing order issue.

By default the Template Engine will start to parse by innermost module variable. So, in your case, `exp:freeform:form` is parsed before `exp:channel:entries`.

You need to make the `exp:channel:entries` be parsed first to make the `{company_email}` available to `exp:freeform:form`. For this, set the value of its `parse` parameter to [inward](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/plugins.html#changing-parsing-order):

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="companies" limit="1" site="default_site" parse="inward"}
  {exp:freeform:form form_name="el_list_form" required="name|email|phone|company" return="/search" recipient1="{company_email}"}
    [...]
  {/exp:freeform:form}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

It's just this.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't using different notification templates for each recipient then you can use a pipe delimited list of email addresses for the admin_notify parameter (or specify them in the form tag parameters)

If you still encounter a parse order problem you might want to try adding a freeform field for the second address and including a hidden field in the form into which you put the second email address.

Then you could try using the name of that hidden field in your form tag.

Something like

```
<input type="hidden" name="second_email" value="{company_email}">
```

Then in your form tag pair use

```
{exp:freeform:form form_name="el_list_form" required="name|email|phone|company" return="/search" recipient1="{second_email}"}
```

Not tried it but it might work.